# Wrong encoding, output file gives � instead of normal char

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I want to make a program that searches a file for desired chars in words (letters č ć ž š), replaces them with c z s etc. and saves the file. In my attempt, however, I get some stupid signs, so that means it opens the file wrongly. When I try to add `encoding.unicode` it gives me errors (shown below). And one more question, how do I make a program which opens files by dragging them in an .exe file.

> Error 3   The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.IO.File.Open(string, System.IO.FileMode,
>   System.IO.FileAccess)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Users\Vulisha\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   14  59  ConsoleApplication1
>
> Error 4   Argument '3': cannot convert from 'System.Text.Encoding' to
>   'System.IO.FileAccess'    C:\Users\Vulisha\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs   14  122 ConsoleApplication1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"C:\Users\Vulisha\Desktop\titl.txt", FileMode.Open)))
            {
                string fileText = stream.ReadToEnd();

                // Do your replacements
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"č", @"c");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"ć", @"c");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"š", @"s");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"ž", @"z");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"đ", @"d");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"Č", @"C");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"Č", @"C");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"Š", @"S");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"Ž", @"Z");
                fileText = fileText.Replace(@"Đ", @"D");

                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"titl.txt", FileMode.Create)))
                {
                    // You do a create because the new file will have less characters than the old one
                    writer.Write(fileText);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If files are dropped onto your executable, they will be passed as command-line arguments.  That's the `args[]` array inside your `Main(string[] args)` method.

Comment: thank you very much on your welcome, i will now play a bit with this string args, and i will pay more attention on that from now on

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to be more careful with placement of parentheses.  You need

```
new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"titl.txt", FileMode.Create), Encoding.Unicode)
```

but you wrote

```
new StreamWriter(File.Open(@"titl.txt", FileMode.Create, Encoding.Unicode))
```

See the difference?

Comment: ohhh i am so stupid :P, Thank you very much it solved that problem, actually I use Encoding.Default cuz Unicode wont work always, but thank you